# Using Grafana to execute a Script

Tags: bash, service, httprequest, grafana, httpresponse

I would like to use Grafana as the main interface for a program for the user, allowing them to run the program that spits out the data the grafana dashboard is visualizing.

I've seen this problem here: https://community.grafana.com/t/create-button-to-execute-a-batch-or-command-file/52705/3

It says that Grafana itself cannot execute programs directly, but I am interested in making a roundabout way, and would like to use this grafana button panel plug in here: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/cloudspout-button-panel/

My idea is to create a program/service that runs by default on the machine, constantly monitoring for a GET or POST HTTP request that clicking the button would initiate.

Has it already been implemented before? Does this sound feasible? Where should I begin to try creating this myself?

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a misuse of Grafana: it is not designed for such level of interaction. All you can do with this approach is to give user a button to start something, no response processing is possible. You'll still need a way to pass data from last run to some data source, that will be later used by Grafana.

Comment: Some combination of linked plugin, json data source and custom http service with two endpoints: start new run, and get last run results way get you what you want. But it still will be a misuse, since incorporation of historicity in this approach is very challenging (if even possible) and thus against of whole reason of Grafana's existence.

Comment: @markalex I may be misunderstanding, are you saying that I have the wrong idea on how the button will execute my program? Is there a reason why we need previous results? I already have my program set up with prometheus and grafana to monitor its output. I wish to allow the user to execute a script that starts my program via a button on grafana.

Comment: So you want simply allow user to trigger program start? Then linked plugin is exactly what you need and you should not have problems. What kind of help you expect to get from us?

Comment: @markalex I don't have experience writing a service that can monitor HTTP GET requests. I would like to be pointed towards resources that can help me get started (preferably in python). I appreciate your help :)

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not how SO works: requests for books  and such are off topic here. And otherwise you question is too broad to be answered reasonably. You need to learn first: there plenty of simple examples of http servers on python in the Internet. And if you have a specific problem in something - you came here and ask about it (first checking if it wasn't asked before of course)